# Validating Uniqueness Across Two Tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, model, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a `Company` and `Archive` model that have the same table structure. Both models have a `validates :name, :uniqueness => true` validation.

In the company.rb file  I'm having trouble setting up a custom validation where when I add a record to the `Company` database it also checks the `Archive` model (so that if a record in the Archive model with that name already exists then it won't be added to the `Company` table).

I'm assuming this is possible to do, but I'm having trouble implementing, can anyone help?

Comment: Try adding a validates_associated :archives to your Company.rb

Comment: you might want to check first_or_create. this might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16644756/first-or-create-by-email-and-then-save-the-nested-model

Answer (score 9, accepted):

company.rb

`validates :name, uniqueness: true`

`validate :unique_name`

```
def unique_name
  self.errors.add(:name, 'is already taken') if Archive.where(name: self.name).exists?
end
```

It is important to remember though that such code level Unique constraints may not work in a race condition among parallel requests unless somehow this can be done at database level.

Comment: If you want to learn how to avoid a race condition, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34049308/how-to-avoid-a-race-condition-when-validating-uniqueness-across-two-tables-in-ra?lq=1)