# How to avoid a race condition when validating uniqueness across two tables in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21012826/validating-uniqueness-across-two-tables) discusses validating uniqueness across two tables, and the accepted answer mentions "that such code level unique constraints may not work in a race condition among parallel requests unless somehow this can be done at database level."

That is, if you have a `User` and an `Organization` and were to validate a unique `slug` across both, how do you ensure this at the database level, or otherwise avoid the possibility of a race condition arising?

My only thought would be to create a related record like `Slug`, which `belongs_to` both models. You would wrap `create` and `update` of these models in a transaction where you also create the associated record. This record isn't used for anything except ensuring the additional uniqueness constraint and raising an error at the database level if this is violated.

Is there a better approach or am I on the right path?

Comment: As you said, you can create a `Slug` model belonging to different models and add a DB constraint, using a unique index: `add_index :slugs, :slug, unique: true`.

Comment: @markets but I would also need to wrap in the transaction, right?

Comment: Ah yes, a transaction to ensure the creation (or no) of the associated model + a DB constraint (unique index) to ensure data-consistency regarding slugs. IMHO it's a pretty decent path.

Comment: @markets thanks! Feel free to write up an answer, or I can add one after I write the code on my end and ensure it's tested.

Comment: Definitely make sure to wrap in a transaction, as scaling this to a system that allows parallel access could create some big disasters. Keep it atomic ;) Great answer, @markets. We'll let you get the big green check for this one.

Comment: Another question: is it not possible to do this in a `before_save`? Would that not be atomic enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go with something similar, but adding a DB constraint to ensure the "uniqueness" of those slugs. So, in summary:

- a polymorphic model `Slug`: `belongs_to :sluggable, polymorphic: true`
- a transaction to control creation (or rollback) of the associated model
- a constraint at DB layer to ensure uniqueness: `add_index :slugs, :slug, unique: true`

Comment: Is it not possible to do this in a `before_save`? Would that not be atomic enough, or is the transaction requisite?

Comment: @JoshSmith Operations inside a transaction can succeed as one atomic action, and this is not happen inside a callback. So, I think the best approach here is to use a transaction and AR bang methods (ie. `create!`), thus, in case of exception, the whole operation roll-backs and your data remains consistent.